# php require() stops script, but the file exist

Tags: php

There is script which stops when it achieves `require`.

```
$fileIsHere='';
if(file_exists($directory . 'wp-load.php') and file_exists($directory . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php') )$fileIsHere='exist';
file_put_contents('_501_plugins', $fileIsHere );
require_once( $directory . 'wp-load.php' );
require_once( $directory . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
file_put_contents('_502_plugins', ''  );
```

So here the file `_502_plugins` not creates and `_501_plugins` contain 'exist' and I assume that require definitely stops script.

1. I've checked that files is in place with file_exist().
2. Tried it with `try catch` but `catch()` not executing and I cant get error.
3. Server log not shows errors.
4. Code works on XAMPP, but fails on real server.

PHP 7.2 (not in the safe mode)
Why `require` can stop script?

Comment: Please make sure that the name of file your require is exactly the same. example `Plugin.php` is not `plugin.php` I faced same problem long time ago

Comment: Is is readable? http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php

Comment: You check, but then run the rest of the code regardless.  The only code that is run conditionally is `$fileIsHere='exist';`

Comment: What does your PHP error log say?

Comment: Does `$directory` end in a slash?

Comment: Mourad: file name correct and it lowercase; Kchason: yes, readable; Greg: yes, with slash.

Answer (score 1):

It should be one of the following reasons:

- Missing permissions (read permission for PHP process)
- File does not exist
- File contains invalid PHP (maybe file transmission to server was incomplete)

Comment: All of these I've checked, but not helped me.

Comment: Set error_reporting to E_ALL. Then check logs or set display_errors = 1 and display_startup_errors = 1 to see the error in frontend. Don't forget do disable display_error and display_startup_errors afterwards for security reasons.